# Flutter/Dart Firestore query: How do I get all docs where today falls between start/end dates in doc?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a query that is supposed (should) get all docs that have a "DateLive" that is lessThan today and a "DateEnds" that is greaterThan today. So the doc is "live" and not yet "ended".

Here is my Dart query...

```
final todayAM = RepoUtil.todayTime000001();
final todayPM = RepoUtil.todayTime235959();
final querySnapshot = await _db
    .collection('things')
    .where('deleted', isEqualTo: false)
    .where('datelive', isLessThan: todayAM)
    .where('dateends', isGreaterThan: todayPM)
    .where('localzips', arrayContainsAny: localZips)
    .limit(100)
    .get();
final thingsJson = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();
return thingsJson.map((thingJson) => Thing.fromJson(thingJson)).toList();
```

When I run the app I get this error, which I understand, but have no idea how to solve...

*I/flutter ( 1781): ThingView ERROR ThingListError([], 'package:cloud_firestore/src/query.dart': Failed assertion: line 484 pos 18: 'hasInequality == field': All where filters with an inequality (<, <=, >, or >=) must be on the same field. But you have inequality filters on 'FieldPath([datelive])' and 'FieldPath([dateends])'.).error*

How do I write this Firestore query?

Thank you for any help you can provide :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be a current limitation of Firestore. It won't let you do `isLessThan` on the `datelive` field and `isGreaterThan` on the `dateends` field in the same query.

> You can perform range (<, <=, >, >=) or not equals (!=) comparisons only on a single field

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries

I reckon you'll need to query one field in Firestore and then filter the other field on the client.

Comment: Yeah I've read about that. Not sure how good it would be to load massive amounts of docs into a phone's memory to then be filtered. I'm investigating Google Cloud Scheduler right now. Looks like I could created a scheduled function that would run every day, or half day, or w/e, and update a single *isLive* boolean field based on the two dates in docs.

Comment: Yep, agreed, loading the data to then filter it clientside would be wasteful. Best of luck with the Google Cloud Scheduler, sounds like a great solution.

Comment: Thank you for the reply my friend. I do appreciate it :-)